# Items are cut when remove item from listbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listboxitems

I have a - Listbox that the property HorizontScrollBar = True ,So when I add a - item which text too long the scrollbar appears. My problem is that when I remove the 'long item' the other items' text is cut, the text is in Hebrew so I set the property RightToLeft = 'True' , When I change it to 'False' it's o.k , but I don't want to set it to 'False'... 
[image: The ListBox Before I remove the item:]

[image: The ListBox After I remove the item:]

Comment: Question when you are using the Add() method .. what are you doing exactly.. are you also using and return characters ..? where is the code..??

Comment: A bug in some Windows controls when using RTL mode!? A-gasp - I'd never believe it! *heavy sarcasm*.

Comment: When I add the items my code: listBox1.Items.AddRange(array of string items) And when I delete :  listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);

Comment: Steve : It's strange to me too, But it happens . So I try to set the RTL to false and the iteams aren't cut , but I want RTL to true... I attached the screen print so believe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting and resetting the `RightToLeft` property after the deletion operation fixes the problem.

```
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.Items.Count - 1);
listBox1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
listBox1.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```